# Cannot start Nioh Complete Edition

Tags: windows-10, nioh

WHen trying to start the game I'm getting this error:

> Error 0xc000007b can't start application

I've tried reinstalling the game and latest DirectX, .NET as well as Visual C++ 2015. None of it seems to work. I'm on Windows 10 64 bit with the latest April Update.

Other games seem to work fine, I don't know why this doesn't.

What else can I try to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

Try to uninstall and reinstall older drivers (i.e 2008 ones). They're often the cause of the problem, even on recent games.

You also can try other steps to make it work: [source](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/how-to-fix-the-application-is-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc00007b-error/#e)

If it didn't change a thing, locate this file:  **msvcp110.dll**, at *C:\Windows\SysWOW64*, rename it or save it somewhere and finally replace it with an other computer msvcp110.dll file (if you have one) and try to relaunch your game.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT:**

- Replace the `d3d_compiler43.dll` file (located in your game installation folder, or in System32 or SysWOW64) by the 64 bits version of the `dll`.

Comment: I had to replace d3d_compiler43.dll with the 64 bit version. Now it works.